# Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script. - phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

Hi I'm following this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2
to set an auth2 token with phpmailer.
The problem is than instead of getting the refresh token, I get this message "Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script". And Of course I'm checking my gmail account.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: My code is just get_auth_token.php from phpmailer, no changes made (apart from my Google credentials)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the script that creates that message](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/get_oauth_token.php#L63):

```php
$providerName = '';
if (array_key_exists('provider', $_GET)) {
    $providerName = $_GET['provider'];
    $_SESSION['provider'] = $providerName;
} elseif (array_key_exists('provider', $_SESSION)) {
    $providerName = $_SESSION['provider'];
}
if (!in_array($providerName, ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Yahoo'])) {
    exit('Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script.');
}
```

That tells you that you have not included the `provider` property in your URL, or it's there but has an unsupported value. Figure out why that is, and you will have found your bug.

Bear in mind that this is a general script that attempts to work with multiple providers; you can simplify it a lot by making it only use a single provider.

Comment: I've tried to remove the check part, but it says "provider unknown"

Comment: So make sure your provider *is* known by setting it explicitly to the fixed value you want, and ensuring the provider instance is of the correct type, i.e. `Google`.

Comment: Nothing, I have an invalid state message.